# Display image with choice column when multiple selections allowed

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a list where we track an employees performance by awarding badges. I have a (multiple selection allowed) dropdown choice column containing the 4 Achievements.

With each selection, I have badge images that appear in 4 separate columns (one for each badge). Here is the JSON that I'm using but it won't display the image:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "img",
  "style": {
    "width": "60px"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "src": "=if([$Achievement] == 'Accountable', 'https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/HR/SiteAssets/ACCOUNTABLE3.png',  '')"
  }
}
```

Here is my choice column:

[image]

Then I have a progress column that automatically adjusts with each additional badge awarded, but this won't work either with multiple selection:

[image]

Any idea why the images won't appear using the multiple selection choice column? Or how to get the progress to work with one multiple selection column?

Comment: What are all 4 Achievements/choices? Can you show us the choice options once?

Comment: Added a screenshot above, thank you in advance

Comment: Check my answer given below. Let me know if it works for you or if you face any issue while using the JSON provided below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON column formatting for each badge column (total 4 badge columns) like below:

**For Accountable column***:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "img",
  "style": {
    "width": "50px",
    "display": "=if([$Achievement] == '', 'none', 'block')"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "src": "=if(indexOf(join([$Achievement],';;'), 'Accountable') > -1, 'https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/JSONFormatting/SiteAssets/sp-logo.png', '')"
  }
}
```

**For Experienced column***:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "img",
  "style": {
    "width": "50px",
    "display": "=if([$Achievement] == '', 'none', 'block')"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "src": "=if(indexOf(join([$Achievement],';;'), 'Experienced') > -1, 'https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/JSONFormatting/SiteAssets/sp-logo.png', '')"
  }
}
```

Where `Achievement` is the internal name of your SharePoint choice column. You can get the exact internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Similarly, you can apply the JSON column formatting for your other columns.

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: That worked great!  The only question left is how to get the progress to auto-calc an additional 25% with each badge selected in the multi-choice column. Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot use the multiple selection choice columns in the SharePoint calculated column formulas.